# 11pt option messes up figure put in with bpchem in articleclass nih

Tags: bpchem

I am working on a proposal for a class. I am using the documentclass `nih`. I put in figures of chemical structures using `bpchem` (see example). When I just use `\documentclass{nih}`, everything works fine, but the font is tiny. If I use `\documentclass[11pt]{nih}`, the structuctures are messed up (see screenshots). How can I fix this/ is there a workaround?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{nih} 
\usepackage[runs=2]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{bpchem}
\usepackage[journal=rsc, tracking=bpchem]{chemstyle}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{center}
        \schemeref[TMP]{spermine}
        \schemeref[TMP2]{cb6}
        \includegraphics{structures.eps}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}

\CNlabelnoref{spermine}
\CNlabelnoref{cb6}

\end{document}
```

What it looks like with `[11pt]`:
[image: 11pt]

What it is supposed to look like/ looks like with only `\documentclass{nih}`:
[image: without 11pt]

Comment: In the `nih` class the option `11pt` is defined as `\DeclareOption{11pt}{\AtEndOfClass{\RequirePackage{helvet}\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}}}`. A quick test shows that placing `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}` in the preamble cures the problem. I have no idea why the EPS text is screwed otherwise, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class `nih` has the (to me rather strange) definitions

```
\DeclareOption{12pt}{%
  \AtEndOfClass{\RequirePackage{helvet}\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}}}
\DeclareOption{11pt}{%
  \AtEndOfClass{\RequirePackage{helvet}\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}}}
```

It is kind of unexpected that specifying an option for the font *size* automatically changes the font *family*... but then the author also hard-coded his name into the class (`\newcommand{\nih@PIname}{Donald, Bruce R.}`, used in the header later) so it is probably meant for personal use anyway, and he shouldn't be suprised...

The option definitions suggest a way around. Placing

```
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
```

in the preamble or using different sans serif font solves the problem.

This leaves the question why the text in the EPS was messed up. I don't have an answer but found the following hints:

- the font used in the EPS I tested this with (a ChemDraw figure) also was Helvetica; it looks like the EPS used by the OP does that, too
- the changes only appeared when the Helvetica font was chosen, `\sffamily` was active, and `\psfrag` (either directly or hidden in `\schemeref`) was used to replace text in the EPS with another text.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with .eps files, which use Helvetica. As soon as I use `\usepackage{helvet}`  and `\sffamily`, the .eps images are screwed up. The problem seems to be the NimbusSans font, which is a free Helvetica replacement. I could solve this problem by doing:

```
updmap --setoption dvipsDownloadBase35 true --setoption LW35 ADOBEkb --force
```

(For some reason I had to do this twice: The first time `updmap` still used default settings, which are `URWkb` instead of `ADOBEkb`)