# Chemnum/PSfrag - Replacement of Characters in eps

Tags: psfrag, chemnum

Using the `chemnum` package, I encounter problems with replacing temporary labels in EPS files. I first thought that it is a `chemnum` problem, but the result is the same using `psfrag` instead of `chemnum`. The problem is: Not only my temporary labels are replaced (correctly) but also other characters present in the EPS just vanish (but not all).

Attached you see on the left my EPS and on the right what I get in the PDF which is produced by PDFLaTeX.

[image]

I think the problem is the setting of the font.

If you have in the preamble only

```
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
```

everything seems fine.

Adding

```
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}
```

or also using

```
\usepackage{helvet}
```

gives strange character-replacement in the EPS.

So probably the more exact question is: How can I set my font to a sans-serif font with `psfrag` working?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage[hang,center,nooneline,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{kvoptions}
\usepackage[plainpages=false, pdfpagelabels,pdftex]{hyperref}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{picinpar}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{chemnum}
\setchemnum{replace-tag=temp}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{listings}

\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\linespread{1.05}

\makeindex

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=chem-angew]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\usepackage{floatrow}
\newfloat{scheme}{htbpH}{test}%[section]
\floatname{scheme}{Scheme}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\replacecmpd{alc}
\replacecmpd{Br}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{test.eps}
\label{test}
\caption{test}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX Barbara. Can you also include your code for this?

Comment: Can you make the `.eps` file available for download from somewhere? Without this file it's hard to diagnose the problem.

Comment: http://n.ethz.ch/~cbarbara/
test.eps is the file.

Comment: This reminds me of http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86916/5049 which showed the same problem...